# Decreasing time interval between image transition in Bootstrap image slider

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

Actually I am new to bootstrap and I was given with task of decreasing the time interval between image change in the UI.

Then I figured out it is happening through bootstrap image slider. Then I searched for this but not able to find anything. I want to reduce time interval between image transitions.

```
<div class="carousel slide auto" id="c-slide" >
   <ol class="carousel-indicators out">
      <li data-target="#c-slide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#c-slide" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#c-slide" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#c-slide" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#c-slide" data-slide-to="4" class=""></li>
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item">
         <p class="text-center bg-inverse">
            <img src="images/sfk_splash1.jpg" alt="" border="0">
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item active">
         <p class="text-center bg-inverse">
            <img src="images/sfk_splash2.jpg" alt="" border="0">
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <p class="text-center bg-inverse">
            <img src="images/sfk_splash3.jpg" alt="" border="0">
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <p class="text-center bg-inverse">
            <img src="images/sfk_splash4.jpg" alt="" border="0">
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
         <p class="text-center bg-inverse">
            <img src="images/sfk_splash5.jpg" alt="" border="0">
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <a class="left carousel-control" href="#c-slide" data-slide="prev">
   <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>
   </a>
   <a class="right carousel-control" href="#c-slide" data-slide="next">
   <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: any chance to see some code?

Comment: Quite hard to believe you didn't stumble upon [the only 2 params the doc offers](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel) : ))

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal Not permitted to show code which should be under MIT license? We are talking about relevant code of bootstrap slider, not your awesome confidential code...

Comment: @all I have figured it out. you can use data-interval attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I got the answer according to my requirement. There are two ways to perform this task

### Using jQuery

You can change the interval using jquery function like these.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#c-slide').carousel({
                interval: 5000 // Here you can specify your time interval
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

### Without using jQuery

You can use data-interval attribute for directly specifying in html only. like this

```
<div class="carousel slide auto" id="c-slide" data-interval="2000"> // In this I have set value 2000 miliseconds
```

There is no need to use jQuery for changing the time interval, and this is the way I was looking for.

You can read this article: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code to change the time interval of slider(carousel), its jquery code, you can change the interval

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#mycarousel').carousel({
                interval: 3000
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#mycarousel').carousel({
            interval: 2000
        });
    });
});
```